# intelliJ Idea not generating cache.js files

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, artifact

With IntelliJ 10.5.1 on Linux using GWT when selecting "Build 'xyz:GWT' artifact" it will often times just build the nnnn.cache.html files, but not the nnnn.cache.js files.  I've tried cleaning the cache, rebuilding the project, reloading IntelliJ but don't know what else to try.

This has happened before, but I don't know what fixed it afterwards.  Rebooting the system?

Comment: Are they not there in the filesystem at all, or just not showing up inside IntelliJ?  I have a regular problem with things not showing up, and the solution is to *Synchronize* the project, which I believe is under the File menu.

Comment: Don't think I've ever used Synchronize.  As far as I can tell they are not in the directory structure anywhere.  I can give that a try though and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: I've rebooted and still the same.  The only js file I can find is the nocache.js.  Now I did apply an update patch from IntelliJ to get rid of the nag screen that kept appearing.  It is always possible that the upgrade patch damaged something.  I used Synchronize and executed the Cleaned Artifact but still get no .js files generated.  Wonder if it is finally time to move to Eclipse.  Deployment in IntelliJ is just nightmarish. Open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA places files generated by GWT compiler to USER_HOME/.IntelliJIdea10/system/gwt/project_name_with_hash/module_name_with_hash/compile/www directory and then copies these files to the artifact output. So you can check whether that directory contains required files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-war <path/to/your/war>` to dev mode properties. It will put all compiled files to this folder.